# Symbolic Parameters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parameters

I have recently (yesterday, in fact) begun trying to learn MATLAB for a couple of upcoming projects. I have a simple question. For one of these projects, I have to write one function that takes in two symbolic equations, *f* and *g*. If I try to run my function before using `syms x y` (since *f* and *g* contain only *x* or *y* variables), I get an undefined variable error. I understand what it means, but I was wondering is there anyway to just pass in *f* and *g*, without running `syms x y`?

Comment: did you check http://en.literateprograms.org/Functional_object_%28Matlab%29 -> function handles

Comment: I don't really see anything there that helps. :(

Comment: I am surprised that you started to learn MATLAB yesterday, and already used a feature I never heard about (I have been using the software for a long time).

Comment: For my project, I have to take in f and g (functions of x and y) and use F(x,y) = [f,g]. I get F(x,y) by using F=inline(F). My problem is actually passing in the symbolic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where your problem lies, but this is how you can do new function definition with two slightly similar, and convenient ways.

**With function handles**: Pass in the function input arguments to the handles

```
x = (-1:0.25:1); % input vals
f = @(x) cos(2*pi*x).^2; 
g = @(x) sin(2*pi*x).^2; 

h = @(f1, f2) f1 + f2;
h(f(x), g(x))
```

**With symbolic equations**: Use `sym` only during construction of the equations

```
% symbolic
f = sym('cos(2*pi*x)^2');
g = sym('sin(2*pi*x)^2');

h = f + g;
subs(h, x)
```

Obviously you can generalize the above for more than one independent variables, i.e. `(x,y).` Hope this is close!

Comment: This helps, but what I mean is this: function myFunc(f,g) is my function header. An example call would be myFunc(x^2,y^2). When I do this though, I get x is undefined variable. How can I stop this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, if x and y are not defined. In any function input arguments have a type and value. So you either pass the value of x and y, for example like in the answer, or strings signifying function components or arguments, i.e. `myFunc('x', 'y')`. This is equivalent to hiding the construction of the symbolic objects inside the function, but it is conceptually the same.